# Hiding duplicates from dropdown when using value relation in QGIS Form

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, vector-layer, duplication, dropdownlist

I've got a vector layer with a QGIS Form and the column `"test"` in the attribute table. I have values for the columns e.g: `abc`, `abc`, `abcd`.

I defined a form for this Layer. The type for the column `"test"` is `Value Relation` and I checked `Use Completer`.

When I create a new feature for this Layer in the form I get a dropdown when I type the first letter as desired. But in the dropdown, I have three options to select: `abc`, `abc`, `abcd`. So `abc` is duplicated.

I would like to remove the duplicates from this list. I just would like to see: `abc`, `abcd`

Is there a possibility to do this?

QGIS-Version: 3.22.9

How-To-Reproduce:

1. Open an empty Project
2. Create an empty shape-layer with one text field
3. In Form use `Value Relation` and check `Use Completer`
4. Add a new feature

Comment: Why use Value Relation ? If you use List, you'll have a complete list of unique values in your `test` column.

Comment: List is greyed out

Comment: So, can you provide more information about your QGIS version, your layer source, etc. ? to help other users to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I added some information to my question. I got the same problems for a local stored shape and a PostGIS-Layer!

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `Value Map` form widget to have a list of unique items, even from a field with duplicate values.

[From the documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#attributes-form-properties) :

> **Value Map**: A combo box with predefined items. The value is stored in the attribute, the description is shown in the combo box. You can define values manually or load them from a layer or a CSV file.

[image: Value Map form widget]

Comment: I cant add new Values with this in the atribute form or can i?

Comment: For me, you can't.

Comment: Then, this isnt an option for me!

Answer (score 5):

The answer by @J.Monticolo should be correct. Additionally, your data may be the source of the problem if there are blank spaces hidden in the values.  For example, your values may include `'abc'`, `' abc'`, `'abc '`, or `' abc '`.

These often arise as data entry errors and are difficult to visually spot.  They will appear separately in a value map, but because the blank spaces are difficult to notice they will appear to be duplicated.

Answer (score 5):

```
"fid" = array_first(array_agg("fid", group_by:="Direction"))
```

[image]

Comment: This changes my values from e.g. "abc" to "(abc)" and completer doesnt work...